# How do you create this gauge chart using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm pretty new to R, and the answers to similar questions I've found out there are going way over my head.

I have a data frame `res` of survey responses. There is a row for each respondent and a column for each question. I want to visualise responses to a particular question `res$Q13` as a gauge chart showing the proportion of respondents who answered "Yes".

The closest thing to what I'm aiming to produce is this: https://pomvlad.files.wordpress.com/2018/05/pomvlad-dials.png

I want a gauge chart that looks just like that one, but I obviously don't need the facet layer, I just need a single gauge chart. I've pared the code (source: https://pomvlad.blog/2018/05/03/gauges-ggplot2/ credit: https://pomvlad.blog/author/pomvlad/) back to the bits I think I need, commenting out the lines I think are unnecessary, and added in some random colours to help me identify which lines of code produce which bits of the chart:

```
ggplot(res, aes(fill = "violet", ymax = 100, ymin = 0, xmax = 2, xmin = 1)) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymax=1, ymin=0, xmax=2, xmin=1), fill = "#ece8bd") +
  geom_rect() + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = -pi/2) + xlim(c(0, 2)) + ylim(c(0, 2)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = "title1", colour = "blue"), size = 6.5) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.5, y = 1.5, label = "title2"), size = 4.2) + 
  #facet_wrap(~title, ncol = 5) +
  theme_void() +
  #scale_fill_manual(values = c("red" = "#C9146C", "orange" = "#DA9112", "green" = "#129188")) +
  #scale_colour_manual(values = c("red" = "#C9146C", "orange" = "#DA9112", "green" = "#129188")) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
  strip.text.x = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  guides(colour = FALSE)
```

All I get is the yellow background of the gauge and the titles. I'm confused about how to make the gauge chart show the percentage of respondents who answered "Yes". Can anyone help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: At a minimum, you need to work with a data frame. Your `df` is just a vector. Try starting with `df = data.frame(value = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", ""))`. And then you'll need to use that column name `value` somewhere in your plot, inside an aesthetic mapping `aes()`. You will probably have much better luck if you look at the *data* used in your example and put your data in a similar structure.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've edited as per your comment. Any idea where I should include res$Q13 in my plot? If I do ```aes(y=res$Q13,...```, I get Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale.

Comment: The simplest solution is get convert your data's format into the format from the blog.  Create a data frame with a single row, with the following variables: "variable", "percentage", "group", "label"  and "title".  Past this dataframe to the ggplot script form the blog and it works.

Comment: I thought of that, but I'd much rather know how to analyse the raw data without having to create additional data frames.

Comment: `ggplot` works very simply if you use a consistent data format. It's usually much simpler to transform your data into a nice summary that you want to plot. Including long transformations in your plotting code like `rag(round(nrow(res[res$Q13 == "Yes",])/nrow(res),2))` is fragile---it's easy to create errors, hard to debug, and annoying to adjust for new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, thanks for the help!

```
Q13.GaugeChart <- ggplot(res, aes(fill = rag(round(nrow(res[res$Q13 == "Yes",])/nrow(res),2)), ymax = nrow(res[res$Q13 == "Yes",])/nrow(res), ymin = 0, xmax = 2, xmin = 1)) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymax=1, ymin=0, xmax=2, xmin=1), fill = "#ece8bd") +
  geom_rect() + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = -pi/2) + xlim(c(0, 2)) + ylim(c(0, 2)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = paste(round(100*nrow(res[res$Q13 == "Yes",])/nrow(res),0),"%", sep = ""), colour = rag(round(nrow(res[res$Q13 == "Yes",])/nrow(res),2)), size = 6.5)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1, y = 1.5, label = "TITLE"), size = 4.2) + 
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red" = "#C9146C", "orange" = "#DA9112", "green" = "#129188")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red" = "#C9146C", "orange" = "#DA9112", "green" = "#129188")) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  guides(colour = FALSE)
```